# Including linphone in a Java desktop application

Tags: java, swing, linphone

I'm not sure if linphone can be integrated into a
Java Swing or Java FX application - which I wish to do. The only support
seems to be android based.

I've searched a lots online but couldn't find any examples of linphone working
in a Java SE environment.

According to Linphone site, it appears that the mediastreamer2 only offers android support. So How tightly coupled is this to Android, what sort of level of effort would be involved in supporting embedding in a JPanel for example?

Does anyone know if this is possible and any advice?

Best regards,

Comment: No, I'm still searching ...